# Sudden Drop in Speed at 1h53

Tags: airspeed

can someone explain why the speed dropped so sharply and suddenly before going back up at 1h53 here: https://fr.flightaware.com/live/flight/MSR799

Comment: Since it's just a single outlier point at 12:41, I think it's some kind of data glitch: it's hard to imagine the plane lost and then regained 100 knots of groundspeed in less than a minute. Perhaps a position update of some kind occurred at that moment?